# Refused to load media from

Tags: .net, content-security-policy, web-frontend

I get this error when i try to load a video content in a page :

Refused to load media from ****** because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'blob:' must be added explicitly.

my meta tag is : meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src data: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'

how can i resolve this issue?

Try to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

As the error message doesn't match the policy you have specified, the reason is likely that your page sets a policy, and you add another policy in meta tag. All content needs to pass all policies, adding another policy can only make it stricter. You should figure out where the original policy is being set and modify it. You can see the original policy in a response header.